# Sending messages on a schedule using telegram bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, telegram

I've got a telegram bot that has to send me my timetable at a certain time.

I'm using requests to work with Telegram API and since I live in Russia (we have blocked Telegram) I need to use proxy. Proxy I use is lowspeed but a couple of seconds is ok for me.  Also I'm using datetime library to get current time and check if it equalls to scheduled time

There'is a block of code:

```
while True:
        updates = get_updates(last_id)

        if len(updates["result"]) > 0:

            last_id = get_last_id(updates) + 1

            if (day == 0) and (hour == 8) and (minute == 0) and (sec == 0):  # for Monday
                print('sending...')
                send_all(stuff.monday)
                print("sent")
            elif (day == 1) and (hour == 8) and (minute == 0) and (sec == 0):  # for Tuesday
                print('sending...')
                send_all(stuff.tuesday)
                print("sent")
            elif day == 2 and (hour == 8) and (minute == 0) and (sec == 0):  # for Wednesday
                if (is_even % 2 == 0):
                    print('sending...')
                    send_all(stuff.wednesday_even)
                    print("sent")
                else:
                    print('sending...')
                    send_all(stuff.wednesday_odd)
                    print("sent")
```

And it does not work. I don't understand why. Maybe there'is another way to check time. It's strange because [in this link](https://djangostars.com/blog/how-to-create-and-deploy-a-telegram-bot/) the author uses the same check method and it seems to work.

Regards.

Comment: Where are you getting the hour, minutes, seconds? Does your code really have second accuracy? I suggest not using equals, but rather greater than with a boolean value that gets set if the function ran for that day... Otherwise, if the condition is skipped because the clock is off, you're not going to run the code. Alternatively, learn about Cron

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Just found a schedule library. It seems it will help me. Also great thanks for recommending Cron

Answer (score 2):

Just use [schedule library](https://github.com/dbader/schedule) if you are in situation like this.

It would looks like:

```
import schedule
schedule.every().any_day_of_the_week.at(MM:SS).do(your_routine)
```